# Simulate named parameters in Java

Tags: java, builder, named-parameters

I write a little web API which should it make easy to create URIs. Each resource class should contain a method `createURI` which takes the needed parameters. This method should use a helper method, `populateUriTemplate`, in the background to create an URI string. `populateUriTemplate` needs key value pairs to populate an URI template. In another language like Scala or Python I would use named parameters, but Java doesn't support them. So the question is: How to simulate named parameters in Java?

The straight forward solution would be to create a map:

```
public String createUri(int id, String name){
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("id", id);
    params.put("name", name);
    return populateUriTemplate(params);
}
```

But I don't like to create a map first and put each parameter to it.

Another idea is to use a static method, `param`, to create key value pairs:

```
public String createUri(int id, String name){
    return populateUriTemplate(param("id", id), param("name", name));
}
```

Looks much better to me!

It could be refined a bit to make it more self-explanatory, even if a few more characters are needed:

```
public String createUri(int id, String name){
    return populateUriTemplate(key("id").value(id), key("name").value(name));
}
```

I've also thought of the [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), but this would force the user of my API to create an explicit builder for each resource class, what would be tedious without a benefit. The type of the parameter is not important, as long as a proper implemented `toString` method exists.

My favourite is one of the both approaches with the static methods above (`param(key, value)` or `key(k).value(v)`). Do you know a better way to simulate named parameters in this case?

Comment: I prefere the second one, Java is already too verbose.

Comment: based on what I see described this is not an `API`, it is just a couple of extremely generic methods with names that make them sound like they are related. related names does not an `API` make.

Answer (score 2):

For some ideas on the builder pattern, you could see [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20140219010937/http://codemonkeyism.com/fluent-interface-and-reflection-for-object-building-in-java/) blog post by Stephan Schmidt.

You also just gave me the idea to do the following, with fluent interfaces, a `Callable`, and a static method:

```
createUri().id(5).name("dennetik").call();
```

Which would require createing a `Callable` class (`CreateUri`) with the static method:

```
public static final CreateUriFluentInterface createUri() {
    return FluentInterface.of(new CreateUri(), CreateUriFluentInterface.class);
}
```

And a fluent interface, like this:

```
public interface CreateUriFluentInterface {
    public CreateUriFluentInterface id(Integer id);
    public CreateUriFluentInterface name(String name);
}
```

Which isn't that much boilerplate code, is it?

(Well, if you tone down that horribly named `CreateUriFluentInterface` a bit, it isn't.)

(You would probably have `CreateUriFluentInterface` extend `Callable<String>`, to be able to reroute the call to `Callable#call()`)

Comment: Cool, I can do partially parametrized functions this way! ^^

Comment: Looks nice, but the user of my API has to create a FluentInterface for each resource class, what I want to avoid.

Comment: One of the benefits of this approach that the others miss is this method gets you compile-time parameter validation, as the "names" are method names, not merely strings. 

In all the purely string based methods, you'll need to put a stack of runtime validation code in there to make sure there's no typos in the keys, and you'll also not be able to refer to keys in your IDE's itellicompletion.

Comment: @deamon: well, technically you could just write an extension for project lombok that generates the fluent interfaces at compile time, and provide to the user of your API.

Answer (score 1):

```
populateUriTemplate("id",id, "name",name);

void populateUriTemplate(Object... nvs){
    for(int i=0; i<nvs.length/2; i++)
        ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you like this approach:

```
class Params {
    private HashMap<String, Object> allParams = new HashMap<String,Object>();

    public Params(ParamEntry...params) {
        for( ParamEntry p : params ) {
            allParams.put(p.name, p.value);
        }
    }

    public getParam(String name) {
           return allParams.get(name);
    }

    class ParamEntry {
        public String name;
        public Object value;
    }
}

public String createUri(Params.ParamsEntry ... params){
    return populateUriTemplate(new Params(params));
}
```

To call it use

```
createUri(new Param.ParamEntry("name", valueObject) );
```

Inside the populateUriTemplate...
just `use params.get("name");`

Comment: You may add a static method to create a param so it would be the same as the second idea proposed in the question.

Answer (score 0):

[Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) does exactly this. As well as being able to bind requests to specific methods in controller classes, you can [bind request parameters to method parameters](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestparam). You can have a look to see how it works, but basically it picks a strategy to map the right request parameter to the right method parameter.

You basically get something like:

```
public String createUri(@RequestParam int id, @RequestParam String name){
    return populateUriTemplate(id, name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is almost silly and slightly off topic, but using Lombok's [@Builder](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder.html) annotation takes this closer to the desired result.

Furthermore if the builder, builder method and build method names are changed to `_` they almost disappear:

```
import static foo.Template._;

class Resource {
    String createURI(String id, String name) {
        return populateURITemplate(_.id(id).name(name)._());
    }
    String populateURITemplate(Template t ){
        return t.id+"="+t.name;
    }
}
@Builder(builderClassName = "_", builderMethodName = "_", buildMethodName = "_" )
class Template {
    static _ _ = _();
    String id;
    String name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Named parameters are not the way:

Named parameters do not make your code any cleaner in this case. I would argue that they make things more complex and error prone in Java because you lose type safety and you lose compiler warnings about identifiers that do not exist.

#### TypeSafe Immutable Fluent Builders:

[I wrote an article on a `UrlBuilder` implementation](http://www.vertigrated.com/blog/2015/08/fluent-builder-pattern-revisited/) earlier this year, it shows a type safe fluent interface that enforces order of construction for mandatory input and allows for optional parts with sane defaults as well.

Now I will be the first to admit that the approach I use is fairly verbose, but it is extremely productive once that initial price is paid. It works with dependency injection and is easily unit testable and most importantly is composable for specialization.

```
    final URL url1 = new UrlBuilder().scheme("http").host("www.google.com").build();
    System.out.println("url1 = " + url1);
    final URL url2 = new UrlBuilder().scheme("https").userInfo("xkcd", "correcthorsebatterystaple").host("admin.xkcd.com").build();
    System.out.println("url2 = " + url2);
```

Produces:

```
url1 = http://www.google.com
url2 = https://xkcd:correcthorsebatterystaple@admin.xkcd.com
```

I am addressing the verbosity of the anonymous inner class implementations of the interfaces with another approach I am experimenting with; [type safe implementations of value objects from interfaces using dynamic proxies](http://www.vertigrated.com/blog/2015/09/automatically-generating-an-immutable-value-object-implementation-for-interface/).

This will do away with the boilerplate value objects and replace them with `Map<String,?>` but put a dynamically generated type safe immutable `Interface` wrapper around them.

I encourage you to read about both of these and see how combining them gives you a better solution than named properties ever would.

When I get time to refactor my `UrlBuilder` with the dynamic proxies I will post another blog post about it as well.

#### Named Parameters via Guice

If you are dead set on named parameters then I would recommend looking at [Guice @Named bindings](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations#named). You still lose the compile type checks and safety but at least you get some validations from Guice.

public class RealBillingService implements BillingService {

```
@Inject
public RealBillingService(@Named("Checkout") CreditCardProcessor processor,
    TransactionLog transactionLog) {
...
}
```